# how to implement searchview filter in android?

Tags: java, android, picasso, searchview, android-cardview

As i was new to android i don't know how to implement searchview filter.Since I used **picasso** to retrieve images from server and displayed it through cardview. My Expected output is when user types the name of the car that particular gridview alone needs to be filtered. Please someone help me to make this searchview workable.

[MainActivity Screen](https://i.stack.imgur.com/hFUWm.png)

**MainActivity.java**

```
public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {

static String urlAddress="server_url";

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
    Toolbar toolbar = (Toolbar) findViewById(R.id.toolbar);
    setSupportActionBar(toolbar);
    //FloatingActionButton fab = (FloatingActionButton) findViewById(R.id.fab);

    final GridView gv= (GridView) findViewById(R.id.gv);
    new Downloader(MainActivity.this,urlAddress,gv).execute();

}

}
```

**spacecraft.java(Data_Object)**

```
public class Spacecraft {

int id;
String name,propellant,description,imageUrl;


public int getId() {
    return id;
}

public void setId(int id) {
    this.id = id;
}

public String getName() {
    return name;
}

public void setName(String name) {
    this.name = name;
}

public String getDescription() {
    return description;
}

public void setDescription(String description) {
    this.description = description;
}

public String getPropellant() {
    return propellant;
}

public void setPropellant(String propellant) {
    this.propellant = propellant;
}

public String getImageUrl() {
    return imageUrl;
}

public void setImageUrl(String imageUrl) {
    this.imageUrl = imageUrl;
}
}
```

**Connector.java**

```
public class Connector {

public static HttpURLConnection connect(String urlAddress)
{
    try
    {
        URL url=new URL(urlAddress);
        HttpURLConnection con= (HttpURLConnection) url.openConnection();

        //PROPERTIES
        con.setRequestMethod("GET");
        con.setConnectTimeout(20000);
        con.setReadTimeout(20000);
        con.setDoInput(true);

        return con;

    } catch (MalformedURLException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    } catch (IOException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }

    return null;
}
}
```

**DataParser.java**

```
public class DataParser extends AsyncTask<Void,Void,Boolean> {

Context c;
String jsonData;
GridView gv;

ProgressDialog pd;
ArrayList<Spacecraft> spacecrafts=new ArrayList<>();

public DataParser(Context c, String jsonData, GridView gv) {
    this.c = c;
    this.jsonData = jsonData;
    this.gv = gv;
}

@Override
protected void onPreExecute() {
    super.onPreExecute();

    pd=new ProgressDialog(c);
    pd.setTitle("Parse");
    pd.setMessage("Parsing..Please wait");
    pd.show();
}

@Override
protected Boolean doInBackground(Void... params) {
    return this.parseData();
}

@Override
protected void onPostExecute(Boolean parsed) {
    super.onPostExecute(parsed);

    pd.dismiss();

    if(parsed)
    {
        //BIND
        CustomAdapter adapter=new CustomAdapter(c,spacecrafts);
        gv.setAdapter(adapter);
    }else {
        Toast.makeText(c,"Unable To Parse",Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
    }
}

private Boolean parseData()
{
    try
    {
        JSONArray ja=new JSONArray(jsonData);
        JSONObject jo;

        spacecrafts.clear();
        Spacecraft spacecraft;

        for (int i=0;i<ja.length();i++)
        {
            jo=ja.getJSONObject(i);

            int id=jo.getInt("id");
            String name=jo.getString("name");
            String prop=jo.getString("propellant");
            String desc=jo.getString("description");
            String imageUrl=jo.getString("imageurl");

            spacecraft=new Spacecraft();

            spacecraft.setId(id);
            spacecraft.setName(name);
            spacecraft.setPropellant(prop);
            spacecraft.setDescription(desc);
            spacecraft.setImageUrl(imageUrl);

            spacecrafts.add(spacecraft);

        }

        return true;

    } catch (JSONException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }

    return false;
}
}
```

**Downloader.java**

```
public class Downloader extends AsyncTask<Void,Void,String> {

Context c;
String urlAddress;
GridView gv;

ProgressDialog pd;

public Downloader(Context c, String urlAddress, GridView gv) {
    this.c = c;
    this.urlAddress = urlAddress;
    this.gv = gv;
}



@Override
protected void onPreExecute() {
    super.onPreExecute();

    pd=new ProgressDialog(c);
    pd.setTitle("Retrieve");
    pd.setMessage("Retrieving..Please wait");
    pd.show();

}

@Override
protected String doInBackground(Void... params) {
    return this.downloadData();
}

@Override
protected void onPostExecute(String jsonData) {
    super.onPostExecute(jsonData);

    pd.dismiss();

    if(jsonData==null)
    {
        Toast.makeText(c,"Unsuccessful,No Data Retrieved ",Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
    }else {
        //PARSER
        DataParser parser=new DataParser(c,jsonData,gv);
        parser.execute();

    }

}

private String downloadData()
{
    HttpURLConnection con=Connector.connect(urlAddress);
    if(con==null)
    {
        return null;
    }

    try
    {
        InputStream is=new BufferedInputStream(con.getInputStream());
        BufferedReader br=new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(is));

        String line;
        StringBuffer jsonData=new StringBuffer();

        while ((line=br.readLine()) !=null)
        {
            jsonData.append(line+"\n");
        }

        br.close();
        is.close();

        return jsonData.toString();

    } catch (IOException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }

    return null;
}

public class execute {
}
}
```

**CustomAdapter.java**

```
public class CustomAdapter extends BaseAdapter {

Context c;
ArrayList<Spacecraft> spacecrafts;

public CustomAdapter(Context c, ArrayList<Spacecraft> spacecrafts) {
    this.c = c;
    this.spacecrafts = spacecrafts;
}

@Override
public int getCount() {
    return spacecrafts.size();
}

@Override
public Object getItem(int position) {
    return spacecrafts.get(position);
}

@Override
public long getItemId(int position) {
    return position;
}

@Override
public View getView(int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {
    if(convertView==null)
    {
        convertView= LayoutInflater.from(c).inflate(R.layout.model,parent,false);
    }

    TextView nameTxt= (TextView) convertView.findViewById(R.id.nameTxt);
    ImageView img= (ImageView) convertView.findViewById(R.id.spacecraftImage);

    final Spacecraft s= (Spacecraft) this.getItem(position);

    nameTxt.setText(s.getName());
    PicassoClient.downloadImage(c, s.getImageUrl(), img);



    convertView.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            openDetailACtivity(s.getName(),s.getPropellant(),s.getDescription(),s.getImageUrl());
        }
    });

    return convertView;
}

private void openDetailACtivity(String name,String propellant,String 
 description,String imageUrl)
  {
    Intent i=new Intent(c, DetailActivity.class);

    //PACK DATA
    i.putExtra("NAME_KEY",name);
    i.putExtra("PROPELLANT_KEY",propellant);
    i.putExtra("DESCRIPTION_KEY",description);
    i.putExtra("IMAGEURL_KEY",imageUrl);

    c.startActivity(i);
 }
 }
```

**PicassoClient.java**

```
public class PicassoClient {

public static void downloadImage(Context c,String imageUrl,ImageView img)
{
    if(imageUrl!=null && imageUrl.length()>0)
    {

Picasso.with(c).load(imageUrl).placeholder(R.drawable.placeholder).into(img);
    }else {
        Picasso.with(c).load(R.drawable.placeholder).into(img);
    }
}
}
```

**content_main**

```
   <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
    <SearchView
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:background="@android:color/background_light" />

     <GridView
       android:id="@+id/gv"
     android:layout_width="wrap_content"
      android:layout_height="wrap_content"
      android:layout_marginTop="49dp" />
  </RelativeLayout>
```

**model.xml**

```
  <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
  <android.support.v7.widget.CardView 
  xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
  android:orientation="horizontal" android:layout_width="match_parent"
  xmlns:card_view="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
  android:layout_margin="10dp"
  card_view:cardCornerRadius="5dp"
  card_view:cardElevation="5dp"
  android:layout_height="150dp">

 <LinearLayout
    android:orientation="horizontal"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent">

    <ImageView
        android:layout_width="250dp"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:id="@+id/spacecraftImage"
        android:padding="10dp"
        android:src="@drawable/placeholder" />

    <TextView
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceLarge"
        android:text="Name"
        android:id="@+id/nameTxt"
        android:padding="10dp"
        android:textColor="@color/colorAccent"
        android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
         />

</LinearLayout>
</android.support.v7.widget.CardView>
```

Here's the detailactivity for showing the description of the product

[DetailActivity Screen](https://i.stack.imgur.com/xIjMh.png)

**activity_detail**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<android.support.design.widget.AppBarLayout
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:theme="@style/AppTheme.AppBarOverlay">

    <android.support.v7.widget.Toolbar
        android:id="@+id/toolbar"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="?attr/actionBarSize"
        android:background="?attr/colorPrimary"
        app:popupTheme="@style/AppTheme.PopupOverlay" />

</android.support.design.widget.AppBarLayout>

<include layout="@layout/content_detail" />
```

**DetailActivity.java**

```
public class DetailActivity extends AppCompatActivity {

TextView nameTxt,propTxt,descTxt;

//Initialize webservice URL
ImageView img;

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_detail);
    Toolbar toolbar = (Toolbar) findViewById(R.id.toolbar);
    setSupportActionBar(toolbar);


    nameTxt= (TextView) findViewById(R.id.nameTxtDetail);
    descTxt= (TextView) findViewById(R.id.descDetailTxt);
    propTxt= (TextView) findViewById(R.id.propellantTxtDetail);
    img= (ImageView) findViewById(R.id.spacecraftImageDetail);



    //RECEIVE
    Intent i=this.getIntent();
    final String name=i.getExtras().getString("NAME_KEY");
    String propellant=i.getExtras().getString("PROPELLANT_KEY");
    String desc=i.getExtras().getString("DESCRIPTION_KEY");
    String imageurl=i.getExtras().getString("IMAGEURL_KEY");

    //BIND
     nameTxt.setText(name);
     propTxt.setText(propellant);
     descTxt.setText(desc);
     PicassoClient.downloadImage(this,imageurl,img);
  }
  }
```

[Project Structure](https://i.stack.imgur.com/XZIyt.png)

[Db Structure](https://i.stack.imgur.com/5vP8F.png)

Answer (score 0):

1:First Create menu with searchView item in it and then inflate that menu in your MainActivity class

```
<item
    android:id="@+id/action_search"
    android:icon="@drawable/ic_action_search"
    android:orderInCategory="100"
    android:title="@string/action_search"
    app:showAsAction="always"
    app:actionViewClass="android.support.v7.widget.SearchView" />
```

Comment: this answer is not enough, it also needs java code.

Comment: same i also looking for the java code functionality

Comment: i added everything accordingy but nothing works no error as well plz help me

Comment: check the size of your list in your adapter class  !! whether the list items are present or not

Comment: did you add the parselist into your staticlist that is in your MainActivity class ?? as i mention in comments in step2

Comment: // add the parse datalist in this static list by list.addall() then pass this list to custom adapter..what should i add in this line instead of the comments

Comment: I replaced your comments by list.addall(Spacecraft) it shows error as Error:(38, 21) error: cannot find symbol variable Spacecraft

Answer (score 0):

```
4:inflate it and then create instance of y0ur adapter class and then call these methods 
    @Override
        public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {
            // Inflate the menu; this adds items to the action bar if it is present.
            getMenuInflater().inflate(R.menu.search_menu, menu);
            SearchManager searchManager = (SearchManager) getSystemService(Context.SEARCH_SERVICE);
            SearchView searchView = (SearchView) menu.findItem(R.id.action_search)
                    .getActionView();
            searchView.setSearchableInfo(searchManager
                    .getSearchableInfo(getComponentName()));
            searchView.setMaxWidth(Integer.MAX_VALUE);
            // listening to search query text change
            searchView.setOnQueryTextListener(new SearchView.OnQueryTextListener() {
                @Override
                public boolean onQueryTextSubmit(String query) {
                    // filter recycler view when query submitted
                    customAdapter.filter(query, "role");
                    return false; }
                @Override
                public boolean onQueryTextChange(String query) {
                    // filter recycler view when text is changed
                    customAdapter.filter(query, "role");
                    return false; }});
            return true; }
```

Comment: customAdapter.filter (or) customAdapter.flterResult??

Comment: add this function in your adapter class as mention in step 3 @Sandy

Comment: customadapter.filter()

Comment: did you check the list size in adapter class ??

Comment: How to check it??

Answer (score 0):

```
        2:  Create static list in Your MainActivity Class

            public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {

            static String urlAddress="server_url";
              public static ArrayList<Spacecraft> list = new ArrayList<>();


            @Override
            protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
                super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
                setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
                Toolbar toolbar = (Toolbar) findViewById(R.id.toolbar);
                setSupportActionBar(toolbar);
                //FloatingActionButton fab = (FloatingActionButton) findViewById(R.id.fab);

                final GridView gv= (GridView) findViewById(R.id.gv);
                new Downloader(MainActivity.this,urlAddress,gv).execute();
    // add the parse datalist in this static list by list.addall() then pass this list to custom adapter
        CustomAdpater customAdapter = new CustomAdpater(this,list);
// then set the adapetr to your gridview

     }
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

```
3:In Your Custom adapter class create function
 public void filter(String charText,String role) {

  if (role .equals("role")) {

            charText = charText.toLowerCase(Locale.getDefault());

            MainActivity.list.clear();
            if (charText.length() == 0) {
// char text is equlas to zero then add non filter list 
                MainActivity.list.addAll(spacecrafts);

            } else {
                for (SpaceCraft spaceCraft : spacecrafts) {
                    if (charText.length() != 0 && 
     spaceCraft.name.toLowerCase(Locale.getDefault()).contains(charText)) {
                       MainActivity.list.add(spaceCraft);
                    } 
                }
            }
            notifyDataSetChanged();
        }
}
    }
```

Comment: what is that spaceCraft.name denotes??It shows me error and when i change getName() instead of that the error gets cleared.

Comment: mistaken .. it actually was sapacecraft.getname()

Answer (score 0):

```
add this log in your getcount() method
then in logcat check it
 public class CustomAdapter extends BaseAdapter {

Context c;
ArrayList<Spacecraft> spacecrafts;

public CustomAdapter(Context c, ArrayList<Spacecraft> spacecrafts) {
    this.c = c;
    this.spacecrafts = spacecrafts;
}

@Override
public int getCount() {
   Log.d("size", "checksize: " +  spacecrafts.size());

    return spacecrafts.size();
}
```

Comment: add this to check your list size @Sandy